# Missing "Visibility" option on Lollipop Calendar

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, google-calendar

Did Google take away the **Visibility** option for a new calendar event in their Calendar app for Lollipop/5.0?  It was present in KitKat/4.4, but I don't seem to be able to find it anywhere.  The full set of options looks like this for a new calendar entry:

[image: new event]

Incidentally, the calendar app is now correctly using my reminder options as set in the Calendar web app, something that never worked right for me in KitKat (I always had to manually add an email reminder to a new entry added in my phone).  So, that's fantastic, but this feels like one step forward, one step backward since I now have lost the ability to control the event entry's visibility from my phone (the "**Default**" visibility selection is what is chosen behind the scenes, which I verified in the web app after adding a new entry via Lollipop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems Google changed its logic regarding "Visibility" option since Lollipop version. Now, the option is available only when the calendar is shared. If not, the Calendar will hide it instead since it doesn't have any effects.

From [Google Calendar support - Change how others view an event](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/34580?hl=en&ref_topic=6110641),

> ## Change the visibility setting for an event
>
> > Mobile
> >
> > > [...]
> > >
> > > **Note**: If you don't share your calendar, you won't see this setting at all.

and

> ## How visibility settings for an event work
>
> [...]
>
> ### Who is your calendar shared with?
>
> > No one
> >
> > > If your calendar isn't shared with anyone, visibility settings won't affect your event. Choosing "Public" won't make your event public. On mobile, you won't see this setting at all when you create or edit an event.